# How many threads is my application running?

Tags: c, multithreading, gdb

In my code I launch at the most two threads:

```
int main()
{
...
        if (!justcrawler)
                pthread_create(&dns_thread, NULL, &dns_resolver_init, NULL);

        if (!justdns)
                pthread_create(&crawler_thread, NULL, &crawler_init, (void *)&config);
...
}
```

When I run the program in gdb I get lots of lines like this:

```
[New Thread 0x7fff56ffd700 (LWP 188780)]
[New Thread 0x7fff567fc700 (LWP 188781)]
[New Thread 0x7fff55ffb700 (LWP 188782)]
[New Thread 0x7fff557fa700 (LWP 188783)]
```

This makes me think that more than two threads are running. What's going on? How can I check how many threads my program is running?

Comment: What does `dns_resolver_init()` do? What does `crawler_init()` do? If you're calling in to somebody else's web-crawler library, then how do you know it doesn't create threads of its own? How many is "lots?"

Comment: No, I'm not using anybody else's library. And no my functions don't create threads of their own. The number varies. I've seen up to a screen full ~30 such messages at once. But they keep coming back. I switched them off with ```set print thread-events off``` They were annoying. But I still don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `info threads` to show all the threads that currently exist.

Comment: thanks. I tried that. It shows the expected number of threads. So far so good. But I'm still left wondering what all the New Thread messages mean.

Answer (score 1):

> This makes me think that more than two threads are running. What's
>   going on?

You can set breakpoint on `pthread_create` and verify this. If you are running only 2 threads, you should hit this breakpoint exactly 2 times. But according to gdb output there are more than 2 threads were created so you should hit the breakpoint more than 2 times.